# Prevent incomplete loading of css and javascript files

Tags: html, css, preloading

I have the problem that some webpages on my webserver are sometimes not loaded completely, for instance it seems that css and javascript are not loaded and therefore the website appears unformatted. Is there a way to force the complete loading of the css and javascript files so that these errors can be prevented. Maybe some progress loading can be shown while the whole website is loaded. I'm sure this is a solved problem but I need some directions where to look for implementations.

Regards,
Juan

Comment: Sounds like either the user has a slow connection, or the web server is *very bad* (or overloaded). In other words, it's an "Internet connectivity problem", not a programming one. You shouldn't be trying to solve this inside the web browser.

Comment: Absolutely! Neither should we be trying to get around IE idiosyncrasies in our html/css. Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that the page takes a long time to load but gets there eventually? If so, you can wait for the [onLoad](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event3.shtml) event to fire before starting up your JS code. If the page *never* gets there, well, that's some kind of server or connection problem, as thirtydot says.